# Footer height of swift theme on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am not able to change the footer height in my WordPress website investdunia.com. As a result of that menu placed on footer and copyright disclaimer is overlapped. What should I do to increase the height of the footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this css code inside your styles.css file at bottom. You can go to this file from Appearence -> Editor. Or add this css code in Theme Options -> Custom Css.

```
div#copyright {
  line-height: 25px !important;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

You can adjust font-size and line-height as well. Just change digits.

Comment: It's done. Thanks. Can you please help me once more. How can I shift the copyright to extreme right side?

Comment: @SumanGayen Please add this css:
div#copyright .div-content span.alignleft { float: right; }

Answer (score 0):

For so far I can see your problem is in `custom-styles.css:` line 1. Try to uncomment this line:

```
font: normal normal 0.8em/1.625px Georgia, Palatino," Palatino Linotype", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
```